# Tricky SQL I cant get...Dates and NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Imagine a table that has some line items

```
LineItemID   CountryID   Date
1             China      6/26/2011
2             China      6/27/2011
3             US         3/21/2011
```

I also have a table that has some rates so:

```
CountryID  ExchangeRateDate   ExchangeRateDateTo   Rate
US           1/1/2011               NULL             1
China        6/1/2011               6/13/2011        6.06
China        6/13/2011              6/26/2011        6.13
China        6/26/2011              NULL             6.26
```

Notice the rate for the US doesnt change its simply a rate of 1 with a NULL for the `ExchangeRateDateTo`.  I can join the tables by the countryID no problem, my issue is for instance how can I join not only the country ID but also to use the FirstTable's date with the 2nd tables ExchangeRateDate/To to get the correct date.

For instance, I cannot say

`WHERE FirstTable.[Date] BETWEEN SecondTable.ExchangeRateDate AND SecondTable.ExchangeRateDateTo`

Because for instance China's rate becomes null (starts from 6/26/2011 till NULL).
So basically I am looking for a way such that I get the result for instance of china using the rate of `6.26` because the dates are from 6/26-6/27.  The rate of 6.13 ended right on 6/26, so it should pickup the new rate.

So my join would be to `countryID` plus using the date range to pick up the right rate, otherwise if i only join by the countryid you can see that that would yield a cartesian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sentinel value

```
WHERE
    FirstTable.[Date] 
                 BETWEEN SecondTable.ExchangeRateDate
                 AND ISNULL(SecondTable.ExchangeRateDateTo, '99991231')
```

You can also do this in the JOIN too

```
FROM
    FirstTable F
    JOIN
    SecondTable S ON F.[Date] BETWEEN S.ExchangeRateDate AND ISNULL(S.ExchangeRateDateTo, '99991231')
```

COALESCE is more portable but has side effects around datatype precedence.

It's acceptable to store 9991231 as the ExchangeRateDateTo date: may not be "correct" but it simplifies code and JOINs.

Edit: to work around incorrect ranges, use a non-inclusive comparison

Assuming the FromDate is the start of the range...

```
FROM
    FirstTable F
    JOIN
    SecondTable S ON F.[Date] >= S.ExchangeRateDate AND
                     F.[Date] < ISNULL(S.ExchangeRateDateTo, '99991231')
```

Change to `>` a nd `<=` to make it more confusing if required

Comment: Right I had tried that the problem is it will yield too many results.  Becuase it picks up the rates that fall right on that single date (6.13 and 6.26 for my case.  For instance look at my test data.  LineItemID 1 has a date of 6/26/2011 so it passes the condition for both rates 6.13 and 6.26 and because of this I get too many results.

Comment: @oJM86o - That's a problem in your **DATA**.  You need to either have a non-overlapping range or account for it in your queries.

Comment: @oJM86o: that is ambiguous. What rate do you want for 26th June?

Comment: @gbn as I said, if its the same date it should use the higher one, the one with the null.

Comment: You said "the rate of 6.13 ended right on 6/26". It ended before. You have a [Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2]). Note no overlap

Answer (score 0):

For  your `ExchangeRateDateTo` comparisons, just use:

`COALESCE(ExchangeRateDateto, GETDATE())`

...which will check for either a non-`NULL` date OR the current date if the date field is `NULL`.